# Unix `at` scheduling with python script: Permission denied

Tags: python, linux, shell, unix

I'm trying to create a scheduled task using the Unix `at` command. I wanted to run a python script, but quickly realized that `at` is configured to use run whatever file I give it with `sh`. In an attempt to circumvent this, I created a file that contained the command `python mypythonscript.py` and passed that to `at` instead.

I have set the permissions on the python file to executable by everyone (`chmod a+x`), but when the `at` job runs, I am told `python: can't open file 'mypythonscript.py': [Errno 13] Permission denied`.

If I run `source myshwrapperscript.sh`, the shell script invokes the python script fine. Is there some obvious reason why I'm having permissions problems with `at`?

**Edit:** I got frustrated with the python script, so I went ahead and made a `sh` script version of the thing I wanted to run. I am now finding that the `sh` script returns to me saying `rm: cannot remove <filename>: Permission denied` (this was a temporary file I was creating to store intermediate data). Is there anyway I can authorize these operations with my own credentials, despite not having sudo access? All of this works perfectly when I run it myself, but everything seems to go to shit when I have `at` do it.

Comment: Check the permissions of all the enclosing directories. Must have r+x.

Comment: Well, I'm working off of a distributed file system here, so I don't have the rights to change all of the enclosing folders to r+x. Just the ones that I own. (This also means I don't have sudo access.)

Comment: try the full path to the script, because `at` (the subshell it starts) might use a different working directory.

Comment: Full path didn't fix it.

Comment: are you by any chance using Cygwin?

Comment: Nope, I'm on Mac OS X using Terminal.

Comment: is your Mac OS X computer the server (attempting to schedule a process on a client) or a client (attempting to allow a server to schedule a process on it)?

Comment: By your description, it would be the server. I'm running a python script from my Mac OS X computer, which then logs into a server and schedules a series of web requests to happen at a particular time using `at` and my `sh` script.

Comment: Your MAC OS X computer (let's call this `Machine 0`) ssh's into a machine. Let's call this machine `machine 1`. What is the OS on `Machine 1`? Are you able to manually ssh into `Machine 1` from `Machine 0`?

Comment: The machine I'm ssh'ing into (Machine 1) is running Ubuntu. I am able to manually ssh into Machine 1 from Machine 0. I am beginning to suspect, since I am actually logging into a University server to do this, that the University has configured it such that I am denied access to run scripts from the scheduler.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21587/discussion-between-inspectorg4dget-and-chiubaka)

Comment: [This other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948176/schedule-at-jobs-with-cygwin) might be of help.

Comment: Well, my further concern now is that the `sh` script isn't working, and I KNOW the scheduler is running my commands with `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** The `at` command tries running everything as a list of shell commands. So you should start your script like this:

```
at now + 1 minute < python mypythonscript.py
```

In this case, the `#!` line at the beginning of the script is not necessary.

Comment: Tried that. Whenever I run the `at` command, I am explicitly warned that commands will be executed using `/bin/sh`. When I attempt to just load up the python file, even with the `#!/usr/bin/env python`, I end up getting a bunch of errors as my python `import` statements are interpreted as some X server command. I am also subsequently given errors of the format `sh: line xx: <variable name>: command not found`

Comment: How are you invoking `at`?

Comment: `at now + 1 minute < mypythonscript.py`

Comment: I actually still don't see what he's trying to say? Does he simply mean that I should use the full path to the python script in my shell script?

Answer (score 0):

Start the script using python not the actual script name, ex : `python path/to/script.py`.

at tries to run everything as a `sh` script.

Comment: Not sure I see the difference between what you're suggesting and what I did already?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on task scheduling between servers and clients recently. I just abstracted out my scheduling code and [put it up on Github](https://github.com/inspectorG4dget/simDistribution). It was meant to schedule several simulations across multiple machines that have all simulations in their filesystems. The idea is that since each machine had a different processor, it would compute each simulation, scp the results back into the server and request the server for the next simulation. The server responds by scheduling a task on the client to run the next unrun simulation

Hope this will help you.

**NOTE**: Since I only abstracted and uploaded the files about 5 minutes ago, I haven't had the chance to test the abstractions. However, if you come across any bugs, please let me know and I'll debug then as soon as I can.

Github seems to be down now. So here are the files that you'll need:

**On the server**:

`serverside`

```
#!/bin/bash

projectDir=~/

minute=`atq | sort -t" " -k1 -nr | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d":" -f1,2`
curr=`date | cut -d' ' -f4 | cut -d':' -f1,2`

time=`python -c "import sys; hour,minute=map(int,max(sys.argv[1:]).split(':')); minute += 2; hour, minute = [(hour,minute), ((hour+1)%24,minute%60)][minute>=60]; print '%d:%02d'%(hour, minute)" "$minute" "$curr"`

cat <<EOF | at "$time"
python $projectDir/serverside.py $1

EOF
```

`serverside.py`

```
import sys
import time
import smtplib
import subprocess
import os
import itertools

IP = sys.argv[1].strip()
PROJECT_DIR = "" # relative path (relative to the home directory) to the root directory of the project, which contains all subdirs containing simulation files

USERS = { # keys are IPs of the clients, values are user names on those clients
        }

HOMES = { # keys are the IPs of clients, values are the absolute paths to the home directories on these clients for the usernames on these clients  identified in USERS
        }
HOME = None # absolute path to the home directory on the server

SMTP_SERVER = ""
SMTP_PORT = None
FROM_ADDR = None # the email address from which notification emails will be sent
TO_ADDR = None # the email address to which notification emails will be sent

def get_next_simulation():
    """ This function returns a list.
        The list contains N>0 elements.
        Each of the first N-1 elements are names of directories (not paths), which when joined together form a relative path (relative from PROJECT_DIR).
        The Nth element is the name of the file - the simulation to be run.
        Before the end user implements this function, it is assumed that N=3.
        Once this function has been implemented, if N!=3, change the code in the lines annotated with "Change code for N in this line"
             Also look for this annotation in clientside.py and clientsideexec """

    pass

done = False
DIR1, DIR2, FILENAME = get_next_simulation() # Change code for N in this line

while not done:
    try:
        subprocess.check_call("""ssh %(user)s@%(host)s 'sh %(home)s/%(project)/clientside %(dir1)s %(dir2)s %(filename)s %(host)s' """ %{'user':USER, 'host':IP, 'home':HOME[IP], 'project':PRJECT_DIR, 'dir1':DIR1, 'dir2':DIR2, 'filename':FILENAME}, shell=True) # Change code for N in this line
        done = True

        os.remove("%(home)s/%(project)/%(dir1)s/%(dir2)s/%(filename)s" %{'home':HOME, 'project':PROJECT_DIR, 'dir1':DIR1, 'dir2':DIR2, 'filename':FILENAME}) # Change code for N in this line

        sm = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
        sm.sendmail(FROM_ADDR, TO_ADDR, "running %(project)s/%(dir1)s/%(dir2)s/%(filename)s on %(host)s" %{'project':PROJECT_DIR, 'dir1':DIR1, 'dir2':DIR2, 'filename':FILENAME, 'host':IP}) # Change code for N in this line
    except:
        pass
```

**On the client**:

`clientside`

```
#!/bin/bash

projectpath=~/
python $projectpath/clientside.py "$@"
```

`clientside.py`

```
import subprocess
import sys
import datetime
import os

DIR1, DIR2, FILENAME, IP = sys.argv[1:]
try:
    subprocess.check_call("sh ~/cisdagp/clientsideexec %(dir1)s %(dir2)s %(filename)s %(ip)s" %{'dir1':, 'dir2':, 'filename':, ip':IP}, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash') # Change code for N in this line

except:
    pass
```

`clientsideexec`

```
#!/bin/bash

projectpath=~/
user=''
serverIP=''

SMTP_SERVER=''
SMTP_PORT=''
FROM_ADDR=''
TO_ADDR=''
MESSAGE=''

cat <<EOF | at now + 2 minutes
cd $projectpath/$1/$2  # Change code for N in this line
sh $3

# copy the logfile back to the server
scp logfile$3 $user@$serverIP:$projectpath/$1/$2/
cd $projectpath
python -c "import smtplib; sm = smtplib.SMTP('$SMTP_SERVER', $SMTP_PORT); sm.sendmail('$FROM_ADDR', '$TO_ADDR', '$MESSAGE')"
python clientsiderequest.py
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try: `echo 'python mypythonscript.py' | at ...`